# Get an asp.net Label control using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label

I have a label control with in a form view that displays the sum of few textboxes.
I am not able to get the id of label tb_TA_2_6 in java script.

i tried

```
<script type ="text/jscript" language= "javascript" >
 function autosum(t1, t2) {
var sum;
var a = document.getElementById('tb_TA_2_6'); // does not work
var b = FindControl(FormView1, t2); // does not work
var c = <%= 'tb_TA_2_6'.ClientID%>; // unknown component tb_TA_2_6
var c = <%= tb_TA_2_6.ClientID%>; //The name 'tb_TA_2_6' does not exist in the current context

var num2 = $(t2);
    if (num2.textContent)
        sum = num2.textContent;
    else if (num2.innerText)
        sum = num2.innerText;
    else
        sum = num2.innerHTML;
 }

function FindControl(parentControl, strId)
    {
        var returnObject;
        for(i=0;i < parentControl.elements.length; i++)
        {
            if(parentControl.elements[i].id.indexOf(strId) >= 0)
                returnObject = parentControl.elements[i];
            else if(parentControl.elements[i].hasChildNodes())
                returnObject = FindControl(parentControl.elements[i],strId);

            if(returnObject != null) 
            {   //if object is found return
                return returnObject;
            }
        }
        return returnObject;
    }
 </script>
```

but none of it seems to work, does anyone has an idea what's going on with the label with id tb_TA_2_6.

The form view looks like

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="labelID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span > Textbox1 </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_TA_2_4" onBlur="Javascript:autosum(this, '<%= tb_TA_2_6.ClientID%>');"  runat="server"  Text='<%#Bind("question6i","{0:$#,#0.00}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>6. (iii) Total Value  </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="tb_TA_2_6" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%#Bind("question6iii", "{0:$#,#0.00}") %>'  OnPreRender="FormView1_PreRender" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

html rendered is like following, I removed the style information in my question.

```
<tr>

                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 697px; height: 15px; border-style: solid;

                        border-color: #6699cc; border-width: 1px; border-top: 1px solid #fff;">

                        <span style="font-family: MS Sans Serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000">6. (iii) Total

                            Value of All Benefits For Payment of Utilities </span>

                    </td>

                    <td class="alignright" style="vertical-align: top; width: 157px; height: 15px; border-style: solid;

                        border-color: #6699cc; border-width: 1px; border-left: 1px solid #fff; border-top: 1px solid #fff;">

                        <span id="ctl00_cph_Main_FormView1_tb_TA_2_6" ReadOnly="true" style="font-size:12pt;">$60.00</span>

                    </td>

                </tr>
```

Comment: please add your HTML source as well. It shows the genereated IDs.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes and appending `;` on `var c = <%= 'tb_TA_2_6'.ClientID%>`. `var c = <%= tb_TA_2_6.ClientID %>;`

Comment: ; is added in the end of each statement, it's just a copy paste mistake that i didn't add ; in the post.

Comment: Great, posted my answer.

Comment: @Stefan - I have added a comment to your answer. I know that I can get label using ctl00_cph_Main_FormView1_tb_TA_2_6. but how to get this id. using client mode as static renders all textboxes with the id that I specify, but labels take id like this.

Comment: Where is the `input` generated by your `TextBox` in the HTML source?

Answer (score 3):

`Label` controls render as a `span` in the HTML.

To access it you need to get it's `ClientID`.

You can change your javascript to:

```
var a = document.getElementById('<%= tb_TA_2_6.ClientID %>');
```

Your `var c` example had the `Label` control name wrapped in quotes so that is why it was failing.

You could also set the `ClientIDMode` to `static` for you page if you want the controls to render their IDs exactly how you specify them.  Then your original `getElementById` will work as expected without having to get the rendered `ClientID`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) for [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) info.

**EDIT:** If your controls are part of a container template you need to access the control differently by getting the container control and then doing a `FindControl` from it.

```
var a = document.getElementById('<%= FormView1.FindControl("tb_TA_2_6").ClientID %>');
```

Comment: I have tried it, it not able to find control tb_TA_2_6. it says The name 'tb_TA_2_6' does not exist in the current context

Comment: i had already tried  '<%= tb_TA_2_6.ClientID %>' it doesn't work either. gives error name tb_TA_2_6 doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: @Mohit Sachan Post what the rendered HTML looks like for the control.  It should be pretty obvious what the issue is then.

Comment: rendered html doesn't take id's as i specified, that why i tried using '<%= tb_TA_2_6.ClientID %> but it still doesn't return the control.

Comment: Why do you have an `ItemTemplate` setup? Are your controls in a grid or something?  See my edit.

Comment: actually this is an .ascx file. i decide in my .aspx file which template to display according to some precondition.

Comment: I have my javescript defined inside itemtemplate and if i use document.getElementById('<%= FormView1.FindControl("tb_TA_2_6").ClientID %>'), it gives me NullReferenceException. and if I define javascript outside itemtemplate then javascript function doesn't gets called at all.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see your ASP.NET Label with ID "tb_TA_2_6" renders as a `span` element with ID "ctl00_cph_Main_FormView1_tb_TA_2_6".

`document.getElementById('ctl00_cph_Main_FormView1_tb_TA_2_6')` would then select the element.

You should also know that your label is created within a `ItemTemplate` in your `FormView` and that it most likely renders multiple items. This is why you can´t access `tb_TA_2_6.ClientID`.

Now, which item do you want your Javascipt to select the `span` element from?

**UPDATE**

It looks like you´re trying to create a table and summarize some value from each row. Here we go;

**ASP.NET UserControl**

```
<table id="myTable">
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Textbox1</span></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question6i", "{0:$#,#0.00}") %>' class="myValue" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

    <tr>
        <td><span>6. (iii) Total Value</span></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="TextBox1SumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question6iii", "{0:$#,#0.00}") class="sum" %>' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**HTML**, example of expected ouput

```
<table id="myTable" class="styledTable">
    <tr>
        <td><span>Textbox1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="SomeGeneratedClientID_00" class="myValue" Value='60.00' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Textbox1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="SomeGeneratedClientID_01" class="myValue" Value='40.00' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span>6. (iii) Total Value</span></td>
        <td><span ID="ctl00_cph_Main_TextBox1SumLabel" class="sum">100.00</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**, jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Bind the change event to all ".myValue" elements
    $('#myTable .myValue').change(function() {
        // Find parent table element
        var $table = $(this).closest('table');

        // Update summary
        sumTableValues($table);
    });

});

var sumTableValues = function($table) {
    var sum = 0;

    // Iterate through all .myValue elements
    $table.find('.myValue').each(function(index) {
        console.log(index, $(this).val()); // DEBUG
        // NOTE: Need to make sure the value is a number

        // Add the value to the sum
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    console.log('sum', sum); // DEBUG

    // Update the sum
    $table.find('tr:last .sum').text(sum);
    //$('<%= TextBox1SumLabel.ClientID %>').text(sum);  
};
```

Created a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx2xT/) for you to play around with, really hope this helps you in any way.

Comment: the id is ctl00_cph_Main_FormView1_tb_TA_2_6, because this form view is an .ascx control template. I am trying to get this label control in .ascx file itself. I load this template based on some precondition in a form view on my main page using loadbindingtemplate. binding mode is set to static in the main form as well, and it renders textboxes with actual id that i specified, but for labels it doesn't take the actual id. i don't understand your question hich item do you want your Javascipt to select the span element from?

Comment: and I know that i can get label using document.getElementById('ctl00_cph_Main_FormView1_tb_TA_2_6'). but i can't just hardcode this id in my javascript.

Comment: Javascript can only access the generated HTML. You´ll need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side code.

Comment: You can access the control within your ItemTemplate by using FindControl. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx

Comment: yes I have tried using Findcontrol like '<%= FormView1.FindControl("tb_TA_2_6") %>' but it returns null.

Comment: That´s because your FormView has one for each ItemTemplate.